# Не работает отправка сообщения по mail()

Tags: php

Всех приветсвую! Хочу отправлять ссылку для входа на сайт, но не отправляется никакая ссылка кроме пустой (a href="#">Ссылка /a>
)

Отправляю не с локального сервера, в php.ini все есть, функция mail работает, вроде бы, корректно

```
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($telephone){
    $login = $telephone;
}else{
    $login = $email;
}

$to = $email;
$subject = "Ваша ссылка для входа";
$headers = "From: TvoySklad.ru <abc@gmail.com>\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
$massage = '<a href="http://qwer.qwer\login\joinsrc.php?login='.$login.'&email='.$email.'&telephone='.$telephone.'&password='.$password.'">'.'Ссылка'.'</a>';
mail ($to, $subject, $massage, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **message**
> Отправляемое сообщение.
>
> Каждая строка должна быть отделена символом CRLF (\r\n). Строки не
> должны быть длиннее 70 символов.

У Вас явно строка будет больше 70 символов. Поэтому пробуйте так:

```
$massage = '<a href="http://qwer.qwer\login\joinsrc.php
    ?login='.$login.'
    &email='.$email.'
    &telephone='.$telephone.'
    &password='.$password.'
    ">'.'Ссылка'.'</a>';
```

А вообще передача логина и пароля в таком виде - это оочень не хорошо!!!

Comment: Спасибо, была мысль о количестве символом, но потом решил, что бред. А как вы предлагаете передавать логин и пароль? Дельный совет найти сложно, тем более, что я полностью самоучка

Comment: Пользователь должен сам эти данные вводить. Но на крайний случай, если нужно залогинить первый раз, можно использовать временный токен

Answer (score 1):

Советую, взглянуть в сторону библиотек для отправки почты, ибо вариант который  вы используете устаревший, и гарантия доставки низка, используйте либо PHPMailer либо аналоги

link of article - https://snipp.ru/php/smtp-phpmailer

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score -1):

PHP использует стандартную функцию mail она прописана в php.ini в переменной mail=

Вот сторока из моего PHP ini.

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/mail.conf --logfile='/var/log/msmtp.log' -a godaddy360 -t"
```

Так вот в своём конфиге, я использовал гейт msmtp и он полностью поддерживает всё.

Comment: Это я знаю, там все, вроде бы, окей. Но почта не отправляет ничего, кроме пустой ссылки и, к примеру, такого текста
    $massage = "Ваш пароль: ".$login_accept;

Comment: @ali вот дополнил.... Чекай ман на msmtp, с него сделаешь любое соединение с smtp сервером, и отправку мейлов...

Comment: ps: И спасибо нехорошим людям, что минусую не полный ответ!!!!

Comment: Т.е. вместо использования библиотеки на php мы будем устанавливать и настраивать msmtp? Прекрасный ход

Comment: погуглите библиотеки для отправки почты на php, mail()-небезопасное решение

Comment: @ArchDemon нет, мы будем каждый раз тащить в PHP вогон мусора, когда всё давно реализовано в msmtp и остаётся просто использовать встроенную, настроенную и отлаженную функцию mail.